# Error in Unite testing. Python template Publish-Subscribe

Tags: python

I have a task:

Need to create an Emitter class that implements the Publish-Subscribe template and contains two methods:

on(event, handler) - 
bind handler to event "event"

emit(event, data) - 
generates the event "event", calls all the handlers associated with this event (if any) and passes them as the "data" argument

I did it in Python as follows:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Emitter:
    def __init__(self):
        self._handlers = {}

    def on(self, signal, handler):
        self._handlers[signal] = handler

    def emit(self, signal, data):
        func = self._handlers.get(signal)
        if func is None:
            raise ValueError('Wrong emit key')
        return func(data)


def print_connected(data):
    print('first: {0}'.format(data))


def print_disconnected(data):
    print('second: {0}'.format(data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    emitter = Emitter()
    emitter.on('connect', print_connected)
    emitter.on('disconnect', print_disconnected)
    emitter.emit('connect', 'http-server')
    # prints to console:
    # > We have been connected to http-server
    emitter.emit('connect', 'websocket')
    # prints to console:
    # > We have been connected to websocket

    emitter.emit('disconnect', 'websocket')
    # prints to console:
    # > We disconnected from websocket
    emitter.emit('disconnect', 'http-server')
    # prints to console:
    # > We disconnected from http-server
```

The fulfillment of these tasks should be accompanied by unit tests that were provided to me. 3/5 of the test code passed, issuing one ERROR and one FAIL. Here they are:

[image: screenshot]

A link to the GitHub repository with a unit test, as well as a template for solving this task.

https://github.com/Quinlys/-Yakymiv_Igor--tasks

The Unite test is located in the folder "test" -> "task-3", the template for the task is located in the "task-3".

Comment: Looks like the problem is in your unit tests code where you mock your call, not in the actual code.

Comment: Never publish external links (other than case referring an existing answer within stackoverflow) - nobody will go there for you. Publish it here, otherwise nobody will see where the problem originates from. The problem is somewhere in your unit tests code, so publish it here.